# Join Two Arrays in ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, cfml

Is there a built-in way to join two arrays in ColdFusion, similar to JavaScript's `array.concat()`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Not really, but guess what, just use Java! :)

```
<cfset foo = [1,2,3]>
<cfset bar = [4,5,6]>
<cfset foo.addAll( bar )>
```

reference: [Java's Collection Interface API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).

source: http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/merging-two-arrays-267

Comment: Oddly enough, underlying Java methods do not work always as expected. I still haven't figure out exactly when and why. I often use Java methods for removing duplicates, joining and sorting Arrays, I remember sometimes it didn't work depending how you create arrays, which operations you perform before calling Java method etc. So pay attention!

Comment: @zarko.susnjar - I know this is an old thread, but the reason for the unexpected results with methods like `removeAll`, `retainAll`, etcetera is that the java methods are not as lenient as your typical CF function. They are usually data type sensitive. So `"2"` (string) and `val(2)` (number) are considered different values/elements. Unless you are absolutely certain the data types in both arrays match, you are better of using other methods IMO.

Comment: Of course, if you are not certain about something, always go the safer and proven way.

Comment: CF10+ user, pls see my other answer.

Answer (score 49):

CF10+, use

```
arrayAppend(array1, array2, true);
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayappend.html

Comment: +1, It is impressive that you remembered this question and came back two years later to improve it.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/), you can use [ArrayMerge](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/3-1-Functions:ArrayMerge) (E.g. `<cfset NewArray=ArrayMerge(FirstArray,SecondArray)>`).

Comment: I've added to Adobe's ColdFusion Bug Tracker as feature request at http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=83397 .  Vote it up!  :)

Comment: ArrayConcat Vs. ArrayMerge Vs ArrayAppend ? Please discuss here: http://groups.google.com/group/cfml-conventional-wisdom/browse_thread/thread/95a4b511128c37ae

Answer (score 7):

Its kinda dumb how coldfusion misses many basic functions that one would expect from a scripting language. Here's one I had to write quickly.

```
<cffunction name="mergeArrays" returntype="array" >
    <cfargument name="array1" type="array" required="true" >
    <cfargument name="array2" type="array" required="true" >

    <cfset arrayResult = arrayNew(1) >
    <cfloop array="#array1#" index="elem">
        <cfset arrayAppend(arrayResult,elem) >
    </cfloop>

    <cfloop array="#array2#" index="elem">
        <cfset arrayAppend(arrayResult,elem) >
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn arrayResult>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CF 10 or Railo 4, you can use the concat() function of the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#concat) to get a new array that is a concatenation of two other arrays (without modifying the existing arrays). Example cfscript:

```
newArray = _.concat([1], [2]);
```

Result:

```
// newArray == [1, 2]
```

Using this method to get a new array is a bit cleaner than creating a new array and calling ArrayAppend on it twice.

(Disclaimer: I wrote Underscore.cfc)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript array.join(s) creates a string out of all of the elements of the array separated by the delimiter s.  A similar function to this in ColdFusion is the ArrayToList function.  As far as appending an array to another I don't believe there is a CF function for that.  Check http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_03.html#3473387 to see the list of Array functions in CF. Or try something like this:

```
<cfscript>
   for(index = 1; index LTE ArrayLen(array2); i = i + 1) {
      ArrayAppend(array1, array2[i]);
  }
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took this from Ben Nadel and used it to perform encryption and hashing. Worked like a charm!

```
<cfscript>
    // Note: BinaryDecode/CharsetDecode return java arrays. 
    // Unlike CF arrays, java arrays are immutable, 
    // so the Java addAll(..) method to merge arrays won't work here. 
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/10760835/104223

    // function to merge immutable arrays the long way
    function mergeArrays( array1, array2 ){
        var i = 0;
        var newArray = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arguments.array1); i++) {
            arrayAppend(newArray, arguments.array1[i]);
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arguments.array2); i++) {
            arrayAppend(newArray, arguments.array2[i]);
        }
        return newArray;
    }


    //convert the saltArray string and CustomerID string to UTF-8 byte arrays.
    saltByteArray = charsetDecode(salt, "utf-8");
    CustomerIdByteArray = charsetDecode(CustomerId, "utf-8");

    //create a new byte array consisting of the CustomerId bytes
    //appended with the salt bytes by merging the two binary arrays 
    //via custom function, mergeArrays
    mergedBytes = mergeArrays( CustomerIdByteArray, saltByteArray );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Actually I think you got it from me, haha .. and looking at this thread, *I* probably got it from @noj's answer and rewrote it in cfscript ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily concatenate two lists like this:

`<cfset combolist = ListAppend(lista,listb, ",")>`

So, first convert your two arrays to lists using `ArrayToList()`.  Combine the two lists with the ListAppend() and then convert the answer back to an array with `ListToArray()`.

I don't know how efficient this is, but the code is very simple.  I'd love to use the arrayAppend() but I'm in ColdFusion 8.

Comment: Just keep in mind it is not a complete equivalent as it will a) drop any empty array elements and b) split array values on whatever delimiter is used `,`. ie The single value `arr[1] ="Doe, John"` would become `arr[1] = Doe, arr[2] = John`.

Comment: Leigh, you make a good point.  This could be worked around by using a different list delimiter, such as ~~~, or ~!~!~! which would not likely appear within the array.

Comment: True, though multiple characters will not not work in this case. In most versions of CF, multiple characters are treated as separate delimiters. ie `~!` means CF sees the values as delimited by `~` **OR** `!`. (Things may have changed in CF10). Using a single character like ascii 30, and [preserving empty list elements](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_21.html), should get it much closer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ColdFusion(10+) has an inbuilt function to append two arrays.

**Script** version : `array1.append(array2, true);`

**Tag** version: `arrayAppend(array1, array2, true);`