# SHA-512 hashing a byte array in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, arrays, sha512

I am using ColdFusion 9

Referencing Ben Nadel's good works on [his blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2357-Hashing-Byte-Arrays-Binary-Data-With-ColdFusion-Before-ColdFusion-10.htm), I tried

```
ucase(digestUtils.sha512(imageBinary))
```

For SHA-512 hashing I get that dreaded:

> The sha512 method was not found. Either there are no methods with the
>   specified method name and argument types or the sha512 method is
>   overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher
>   reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided
>   arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method
>   exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.

Now I know that sha512 does indeed exist as a method, because I saw it [here](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html), but when I perform a

```
cfdump var="#digestUtils#"
```

I only get:

```
md5(byte[])     byte[]
md5(java.lang.String)   byte[]
md5Hex(byte[])  java.lang.String
md5Hex(java.lang.String)    java.lang.String
sha(java.lang.String)   byte[]
sha(byte[])     byte[]
shaHex(java.lang.String)    java.lang.String
shaHex(byte[])  java.lang.String
```

What happened to the other methods? I guess I have to try something else.

Please advise with a ColdFusion solution. A ColdFusion/Java solution would be ok too.
I'm trying to write a SSO application where the 3rd party guys feeds me URL parameters. I have successfully decoded the 1st parameter to get my XML Post. I now need to take the 2nd parameter which is the hash payload and go through the algorithm to ensure my 1st parameter hasn't been tampered with.

=========
Editing begins here: Okay,I tried writing the code again to no avail.

The algorithm sounds simple enough. But trying to implement it is killing me.

```
1. compute the hash string value of the XMLPost string above:
 a. convert the base64 salt string to a UTF-8 byte array.
 b. convert the base64 XML payload string to a UTF-8 byte array.
 c. create a new byte array consisting of the XML payload bytes from step b, appended with the salt bytes from step a.
 d. perform a SHA512 hash on the concatenated byte array from step c, which results in a hashed byte array.
 e. create a new byte array consisting of the hashed bytes from step d, appended with the salt bytes from step a.
 f. convert the result of step e to a base64-encoded string and should be the value of query string parameter "h" payload hash.
```

xmlPost was created by my third party guys as such:
This XML payload string was converted to a UTF-8 byte array, which was then converted to a base-64 string. The resulting base-64 string is the value of my xmlPost below.

So I do this:

```
<code>
<cfset xmlPost = urlDecode("PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8%2bPEVzdG9yZVNzb0N1c3RvbWVyIHhtbG5zOnhzaT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEtaW5zdGFuY2UiIHhtbG5zOnhzZD0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMS9YTUxTY2hlbWEiPjxDdXN0b21lcklkPjExMjk0MDwvQ3VzdG9tZXJJZD48RGVhbGVyQ29kZT5OODg4ODg8L0RlYWxlckNvZGU%2bPFBvaW50QmFsYW5jZT4yODA8L1BvaW50QmFsYW5jZT48Rmlyc3ROYW1lPkZhaXRoPC9GaXJzdE5hbWU%2bPExhc3ROYW1lPkh1dHVsYTwvTGFzdE5hbWU%2bPC9Fc3RvcmVTc29DdXN0b21lcj4%3d") />
<cfset salt = "3dfjh674!MujErf98344@090" />
<cfset payload_hash = urlDecode("EtLDRJfcRESFKpY4OGZZnRSN2THqT%2bEelzOuXVU06jotd2kE4yKnlYay7BqyAdcUSATRgSMaHxZa6uBqKKd9rjNkZmpoNjc0IU11akVyZjk4MzQ0QDA5MA%3d%3d") />

<cfset strXML = ToString( ToBinary( xmlpost ) ) /> <!--- to get actual XML --->

<!--- base64 encoding returns a byte array --->
<cfset saltByteArray = toBase64( salt, "utf-8" )  /> 
<cfset xmlpostByteArray = toBase64( xmlPost, "utf-8" ) />
<!--- append salt to xmlpost --->
<cfset xmlpostsaltByteArray = xmlpostByteArray & saltByteArray />

<!--- now let us perform a sha512 hash on this concatenated byte array --->
<cfscript>
// Create an instance of our DigestUtils class
digestUtils = createObject("java","org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils");
// I hash a byte array using the given algorithm and return a
// 32-character Hexadecimal string. Home-made hash function for CF9 and earlier
function hashBytes( bytes, algorithm = "SHA-512" ){
    // Get our instance of the digest algorithm that we'll use
    // to hash the byte array.
    var messageDigest = createObject( "java", "java.security.MessageDigest" ).getInstance( javaCast( "string", algorithm ) );

    // Get the digest for the given byte array. This returns the
    // digest (i.e., hash) in byte-array format.
    var digest = messageDigest.digest( bytes );

    // Now that we have our digested byte array (i.e., our hash as another byte
    // array), we have to convert that into a HEX string. So, we'll need a HEX buffer.
    var hexBuffer = [];

    // Each integer in the byte digest needs to be converted into
    // a HEX character (with possible leading zero).
    for (byte =1 ;byte LTE ArrayLen(digest);byte = byte + 1) {
    //for ( var byte in digest){
        // Get the hex value for this byte. When converting the
        // byte, only use the right-most 8 bits (last 8 bits of the integer)
        // otherwise the sign of the byte can create oddities

        var tail = bitAnd( 255, byte );

        // Get the hex-encoding of the byte.
        var hex = ucase( formatBaseN( tail, 16 ) );

        // In order to make sure that all of the HEX characters
        // are two-digits, we have to prepend a zero for any
        // value that was originally LTE to 16 (the largest value
        // that won't result in two HEX characters).
        arrayAppend( hexBuffer, (tail <= 16 ? ("0" & hex) : hex) );
    }

    // Return the flattened character buffer.
    return( arrayToList( hexBuffer, "" ) );
}

// Get the hash of the byte array using our hashBytes() function
hashByteArray = hashBytes( xmlpostsaltByteArray );  
</cfscript>


<!--- The hashByteArray is in HEX format now. Convert to binary --->
<!--- You must binary decode the hashed string before converting it to binary --->
<cfset hashByteArray = toBase64( BinaryDecode( hashByteArray, 'HEX' ) ) />

<!--- The final step is to append this new hashbytearray with the salt byte array --->

<cfset hashByteArray = hashByteArray & saltByteArray />

<!--- now convert this value to a base64 encoded string --->

<cfset hashByteArray2 = toBase64( hashByteArray )/>
```

Here is what I get for my strXML variable:

```
Actual xml structure converted from base 64 to string:
<?xml version="1.0"?><EstoreSsoCustomer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><CustomerId>112940</CustomerId><DealerCode>N88888</DealerCode><PointBalance>280</PointBalance><FirstName>Faith</FirstName><LastName>Hutula</LastName></EstoreSsoCustomer>
```

The final value, hasByteArray2 is not even remotely similar to payload_hash

This is my first time doing this and my understanding of hashing, byte arrays and character conversions flew out of the window decades ago.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you
Faith Sloan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DigestUtils.sha512](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha512%28byte%5B%5D%29) was added in version 1.4. ColdFusion 9 uses an older version, 1.3. That is why the method is not found.

Use the other function based on `MessageDigest`. Just be sure to pass in the correct algorithm ie:

```
    imageHash = hashBytes( imageBinary, "SHA-512" );
```

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the updated code, some of the instructions may be a bit misleading. I believe they just mean decode the `xml` and `salt` strings from their given encoding (base64 and utf-8) into *byte arrays*, not strings:

```
    // note: salt value has invalid characters for base64
    // assuming it is a plain utf-8 string
    saltArray = charsetDecode(salt, "utf-8");
    xmlByteArray = binaryDecode(xmlPost, "base64");
```

Then merge the two binary arrays (see custom function)

```
    mergedBytes = mergeArrays( xmlByteArray, saltArray );
```

Calculate the hash of the new byte array:

```
    messageDigest = createObject( "java", "java.security.MessageDigest" );
    messageDigest = messageDigest.getInstance( javaCast( "string", "SHA-512") );
    hashedByteArray = messageDigest.digest( javacast("byte[]", mergedBytes) );
```

Merge the arrays again:

```
    mergedBytes = mergeArrays( hashedByteArray, saltArray);
```

Finally convert the binary to base64 and compare:

```
    calculatedPayload = binaryEncode( javacast("byte[]", mergedBytes), "base64");

    // check results
    arePayloadsEqual = compare(calculatedPayload, payload_hash) eq 0;
    WriteDump("arePayloadsEqual="& arePayloadsEqual);
    WriteDump("calculatedPayload="& calculatedPayload);
    WriteDump("payload_hash="& payload_hash);
```

*Note*: `BinaryDecode/CharsetDecode` return java arrays. Unlike CF arrays, they are immutable (ie cannot be changed). So the [handy addAll(..) trick](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/merging-two-arrays-267) will not work here.

```
    // merge immutable arrays the long way
    function mergeArrays( array1, array2 ){
        var i = 0;
        var newArray = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arguments.array1); i++) {
            arrayAppend(newArray, arguments.array1[i]);
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arguments.array2); i++) {
            arrayAppend(newArray, arguments.array2[i]);
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: I tried and tried and tried to no avail to get the hash values to match. See edited post above.

Comment: I do not see any edits yet. Let me know when you post the sample values.

Comment: The sample values are in the code. xmlpost, salt, and payload_hash. my computed hash should be the same as payload_hash. But it isn't. I also showed you the strXML I decoded and it is correct for xmlpost. My problem is hashing.

Comment: @FaithSloan - Thanks for posting the code. Now I see the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: Leigh, you are WONDERFUL! I tried to vote your answer up BUT I am a newbie in this venue and don't have enough reputation points. Thumbs up to you! When I get enough points, I WILL come back to vote your answer as THE ANSWER!

Comment: Thanks, glad I was able to help :)