# ColdFusion Encryption from .NET Membership Tables

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, coldfusion, bluedragon

I have a client who is implementing ZNode which uses the aspnet_Membership table to store a password. This table contains an encrypted password, the password salt and is using the "PasswordFormat" of 2. From what I gather, "2" is a recoverable encrypted password.

The ColdFusion server is BlueDragon 9 Alpha. If you don't know BD, no worries, anything that ColdFusion supports "should" work and I have CF 10 to test it on as well.

If you know a better way to do this I'm all ears. I need to be able to create a user/password and store it in the ASP membership table via ColdFusion. In addition I need to be able to check the user/password for login.

When looking at the Web.config file, the ZnodeMembershipProvider is a "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" type.

The machineKey entry looks like this: (took out the two key values)

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" 
     decryptionKey="[64 character string]" 
     validation="SHA1" 
     validationKey="[128 character string]"/>
```

If I try something like this:

```
Encrypt('myPassword', '[64 character string]', 'AES', 'Base64')
```

It says "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm."

I'm not very savy on encryption or .NET. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that .NET Password tables use Triple-DES, not AES. Try this instead.

```
Encrypt('myPassword', '[64 character string]', '3DES', 'Base64')
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer I wrote up, about [DNN (Dot Net Nuke) authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524877/authenticating-dotnetnuke-users-in-coldfusion/12572268#12572268), should do the trick. (Assuming no differences between ACF and BD). Essentially there are few difference in how .NET and CF handle encryption. The primary differences are:

1. **Encoding**:

   - .NET uses `UTF-16LE`
   - CF always uses `UTF-8`. In ACF, this means you must use `encryptBinary` instead of `encrypt`. (I am not sure about OBD).
2. **Key Format**:

   - .NET uses hexadecimal
   - CF typically uses base64, so you may need to convert the keys first.
3. **Encryption Mode**:

   - .NET defaults to `CBC` mode (requires IV)
   - CF defaults to `ECB` (no IV required)

In case the other link dies, here is the full example. While it uses `3DES`, the basic concept is the same for `AES`. Note: In Java, the larger key sizes (ie 192,256) [are only available if the Sun Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files are installed](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/strong-encryption-coldfusion-mx-7.html).

**3DES Example:**

```
// sample valus
plainPassword = "password12345";
base64Salt    = "x7le6CBSEvsFeqklvLbMUw==";
hexDecryptKey = "303132333435363738393031323334353637383930313233";

// first extract the bytes of the salt and password
saltBytes = binaryDecode(base64Salt, "base64");
passBytes = charsetDecode(plainPassword, "UTF-16LE" );

// next combine the bytes. note, the returned arrays are immutable, 
// so we cannot use the standard CF tricks to merge them   
// NOTE: If BlueDragon does not include "org.apache.commons...."
// just loop through the arrays and merge them manually
ArrayUtils = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils");
dataBytes = ArrayUtils.addAll( saltBytes, passBytes );

// convert DNN hex key to base64 for ColdFusion
base64Key  = binaryEncode(binaryDecode( hexDecryptKey, "hex"),  "base64");

// create an IV and intialize it with all zeroes
// block size:  16 => AES, 8=> DES or TripleDES 
blockSize = 8; 
iv = javacast("byte[]", listToArray(repeatString("0,", blocksize)));

// encrypt using CBC mode 
bytes = encryptBinary(dataBytes, base64Key, "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding", iv);

// result: WBAnoV+7cLVI95LwVQhtysHb5/pjqVG35nP5Zdu7T/Cn94Sd8v1Vk9zpjQSFGSkv 
WriteOutput("encrypted password="& binaryEncode( bytes, "base64" ));
```

Comment: Chris - Oops I wrote this thinking you were using OBD (java based) but it should work the same. The only glitch might be the use of the `org.apache.commons` classes to merge two arrays. But it is not really necessary, you could just merge them manually instead.