# Coldfusion 9 Hash Binary SHA-256

Tags: hash, coldfusion, binary, sha256

I have a problem with hashing binary data. I need to do get the SHA-256 Hash of a PDF-File located on a server. I do it like this:

```
<cfset t01= getTickCount()>
<cfhttp
    name="inv1"
    method="get"
    getAsBinary="yes"
    url="http://url.to.pdf.com/INVOICEXY.pdf" 
    result="inv"
    />

<cfset t02= getTickCount()>

<cfoutput>
    <cfdump var="#inv.Filecontent#" />
    CFHTTP: #t02 - t01# ms
</cfoutput>


<cfscript>

imageBinary = inv.Filecontent;
function hashBytes( bytes ){

    // Get our instance of the digest algorithm that we'll use
    // to hash the byte array.
    var messageDigest = createObject( "java", "java.security.MessageDigest" ).getInstance("SHA-256");

    // Get the digest for the given byte array. This returns the
    // digest in byte-array format.
    var digest = messageDigest.digest( bytes );

    // Now that we have our digested byte array (as another byte
    // array), we have to convert that into a HEX string. For
    // this, we'll need a HEX buffer.
    writeDump(digest);
    var hexBuffer = [];

    // Each integer in the byte digest needs to be converted into
    // a HEX character (with possible leading zero).
    for (i = 1 ; i <= arrayLen( bytes ) ; i++){

        // Get only the last 8-bits of the integer.
        var tail = bitAnd( 255, bytes[i] );

        // Get the hex-encoding of the byte.
        var hex = ucase( formatBaseN( tail, 16 ) );

        // In order to make sure that all of the HEX characters
        // are two-digits, we have to prepend a zero for any
        // value that was originall LTE to 16 - the largest value
        // that won't result in two HEX characters.
        arrayAppend(
            hexBuffer,
            (tail <= 16 ? ("0" & hex) : hex)
        );

    }

    // Return the flattened character buffer.
    return( arrayToList( hexBuffer, "" ) );

}

imageHash = hashBytes( imageBinary );

// Create an instance of our DigestUtils class - this class
// simplifies some of the operations we just saw in the
// MessageDigest class above, turning them into simple,
// one-line calls.

writeOutput( "Fingerprint:SHA " & imageHash );
```

The function `hashBytes` is from Ben Nadel. The output I get from this function is a huge mess consisting of 53760 characters. I don't know what I'am doing wrong.

I also tried this:

```
<cfscript>

 imageBinary = inv.Filecontent;
 digestUtils = createObject(
        "java",
        "org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils"
    );

    // Get the hash of the byte array using our hashBytes() function
    // which dips down into the Java layer directly.
    imageHash = ucase( digestUtils.sha256Hex( imageBinary ) );

    // Output the image "fingerprint".
    writeOutput( "Fingerprint: " & imageHash );

</cfscript>
```

Here I get an Error

> The sha256Hex method was not found

although I have the `commons-codec-1.8.jar` in the `wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib` folder, which should contain a version of DigestUtils including `sha256Hex()`

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**
I solved the problem for the long return of chars. It was a horrible mistake. In the original Code of Ben Nadel was this line of code `for (var byte in digest){...` which does not work in Coldfusion 9. So I changed it to this: `for (i = 1 ; i <= arrayLen( bytes ) ; i++){...` instead of this: `for (i = 1 ; i <= arrayLen( digest ) ; i++){...` and `var tail = bitAnd( 255, bytes[i] );` to `var tail = bitAnd( 255, digest[i] );`

Comment: If you cfdump the variable "digestUtils" is the function listed there? If not maybe a another jar's contains the same class and is being used instead. Maybe an older version?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the same issue as this thread: [SHA-512 hashing a byte array in ColdFusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760272/sha-512-hashing-a-byte-array-in-coldfusion/10760835#10760835). CF ships with an older version of the jar (lacking the convenience method sha256Hex). The older jar is being loaded first. Hence why the method is not found. For the older version, try using `messageDigest.getInstance( javaCast( "string", "SHA-256 ") );` and convert the returned bytes to hex with `BinaryEncode(binarydata, "hex")`. Since this sounds like a duplicate, voting to close.

Comment: (Edit) Adding the jar to "wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib"  only works if the CF server does not already contain that library. In this case it does, and the older version (CF's version) is being loaded first. To load multiple versions of a library you need to use a custom class loader like [JavaLoader.cfc](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/). Though in this case it is simpler to use the approach above instead. *RE: which does not work in Coldfusion 9* Support for cfscript `for .. in` loops with arrays [was added in 9.0.1](http://christierney.com/2012/02/14/looping-over-arrays-in-coldfusion-9-01-cfscript/).